# BigDecimal losing precision on divide

Tags: java, kotlin, rounding, bigdecimal

Consider the following BigDecimals

```java
BigDecimal("6.0000").precision() // = 5
BigDecimal("0.20000").precision() // = 5
```

When you divide those BigDecimals:

```java
BigDecimal("6.0000").divide(BigDecimal("0.20000")) // = 3E+1
```

And

```java
BigDecimal("6.0000").divide(BigDecimal("0.20000")).precision() // = 1
```

So dividing two BigDecimals with a precision of 5 results in BigDecimal with a precision of 1. Even when explicitly setting the precision to 5 by providing a `MathContext`, the result is the same:

```java
BigDecimal("6.0000").divide(BigDecimal("0.20000"), MathContext(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)) // = 3E+1
```

When I set the `scale` on the other hand, I end up with a higher precision

```java
BigDecimal("6.0000").divide(BigDecimal("0.20000"), 5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).precision() // = 7
```

Is there a way to keep the precision when performing a division as above? Is this only possible by specifying a `scale` instead of a `precision`?

Regarding the `scale`, the javadoc states that the *preferred* scale for divisions is `dividend.scale() - divisor.scale()`. However, it also states that

> These scales are the ones used by the methods which return exact arithmetic results; except that an exact divide may have to use a larger scale since the exact result may have more digits. For example, 1/32 is 0.03125.

Isn't that the case in the above situation, as the exact results requires more digits?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with precision until you need to convert the values to strings. `MathContext(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)` would help with keeping precision at a certain level during calculations but for the calculations itself it doesn't matter whether the value is 30, 30.0 or 30.000 (it's always the same numerical value). Just set the scale in the end when returning the result or converting it to a string (that's the only situation where those trailing zeros matter).

Comment: @Sweeper it's Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it [does not really matter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVTXPUF4Oz4), because the result is precise. If you need concrete precision (maybe for parsing), use `setScale` on the end.

If a function would need to lose precision to give you a result (for instance, because of dividing 1 by 3), dividing would throw an exception (in case of using the `divide` function, because Kotlin `div` operator would round the result, losing precision). That is why it is better to set precision and rounding mode by yourself when you divide.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal
import java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN

fun main() {
    val a = BigDecimal("1.0")
    val b = BigDecimal("3.0")
    val c = a.divide(b, 10, HALF_EVEN)
    println(c) // 0.3333333333
    println(c.precision()) // 10
}
```